# abstract class to enforce different constructor signature to derived classes

Tags: typescript

I have base class using another, derived need to make instances of T:

```
export abstract class BaseDefiningModelType<T> {
    public readonly modelType: new () => T;
    constructor(type: new () => T) { this.modelType = type; }
}
```

The abstract base can have derived abstracts (with different constructor signature)

```
export abstract class SpecializedBase<T> extends BaseDefiningModelType<T> {
    constructor(options: {[key: string]: any);
}
```

Examples of implementation classes

```
export class BaseImpl extends BaseDefiningModelType<Foo> {
    private opt1: string;
    constructor(options: { opt1?: string }) {
        super(Foo);
        this.opt1 = options.opt1 || 'default';
}

export class SpecializedImpl extends SpecializedBase<Bar> {
    private opt1: string;
    constructor(options: { opt1?: number }) {
        super(options);
        this.opt1 = options.opt1 || 'default';
    }
}
```

Then I need to reference implementation types

```
const myTypes: (new (options: {[key: string]: any}) => BaseDefiningModelType<any>[] = [
    BaseImpl, SpecializedImpl,
]
```

But BaseDefiningModelType has a different constructor signature (to be used internally by derived classes [but not by code *using* those classes]).
ModelType should be readonly and abstracted to implementations consumers.

Any thoughts about how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but as far as I know, you can't dictate the constructor signature offered by subclasses. That's just not a feature TypeScript has.

So the question becomes: What can you do instead? There are at least a couple of options.

You could make `modelType` a `public readonly abstract` property (or possibly a `protected` one, but it's `public` in the question). That way, concrete implementations are required to provide and initialize it as part of construction, but it's not exposed in a constructor signature and code using the subclasses can't write to it. Here's a simplified example:

```typescript
abstract class BaseDefiningModelType<T> {
    public readonly abstract modelType: new () => T;

    // An example usage to demonstrate the property can be used
    // (not part of the answer's solution)
    createModelObject() {
        return new this.modelType();
    }
}

class SpecializedBase extends BaseDefiningModelType<Date> {
    public readonly modelType: new () => Date;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.modelType = Date; // Initializing the property
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgERwDMBLAOzIHMBZAewBMdkAVATwAccAeJgPgQG8AUAhEI2AVxDJisBFBzA6NUshYJQkGPAQBbeo1YcAXAlI4A7ggAUASgQBePkwDcg4aID0HhAEFSCHAAPYB02ZBwEcTBgCgiIGgQGPVJNYAg4gAsItigaDigINVhgfxAIqJw6dxEva1IaRDZgAoQaQgQILPUU8xwoAHIMMBpkcQhiZRtqpHk0nFoGZAB5EAArHHhbAWnRORwIcSh-M0tO4jAAOj1FwxxbV12AX0FnwRQ0DABlDlhiYGkAF6VbBgCJBdKkOgYEH4IhkSgLAzsLh4OZ8IS7CRSGR7RTKVS6fTMZEmE7WOyOBCo9IPUSwZSacTwGhQLYY3aiMDifL3HaiM6Xa5IjgOKlzZwIWoASXI43+xABlA6XRyeT6hWmz1e9JSiDIkBKsAi9lMFgQ3w2f0BwNwvJ1kFaa1F+oghpwF1gs3SiOWaw2EDtDJG7uQNAoVhoaxsziAA)

A second option, which I don't think works as well, is to expose a `protected` "initialization" method that subclasses can call to provide the `T` constructor. I don't like that as much because TypeScript can't provide a compile-time error if a subclass doesn't make that call, and because it means `modelType` has to be `T | null` or `T | undefined` or some such, and then you have to assert it's not `null`/`undefined` every time you use it in the base class.

Comment: First option looks good but as I don't need a method to provide instance, it could be replaced by an interface: export interface IDefiningModelType<T> { readOnly modelType: new () => T }. It becomes the responsability of the implementation to set the type in the constructor, no matter how. Then make an abstract class with impl constructor signature (empty) as abstract constructors are not allowed

Comment: @Harps - Sure, the `createModelObject` method was just an example to indicate that the base could use the property without requiring assertions, not part of the suggested solution. And yes, you can spin it a lot of ways, the fundamental thing is to make the implementing class provide that feature in another way rather than calling the constructor you want them not to have. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder thank you to show me the way